# Some Plotly plots not showing in JupyterLab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have successfully installed the Plotly python libraries to work with JupyterLab. I have the proper extensions installed. (All directions were followed according to: https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/ )

Most basic plots show up in my notebook file just fine, with interactivity working great! However, some plots are not appearing, and I have no idea why.

For example, the following works just fine:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", 
                 color="species", marginal_y="rug", marginal_x="histogram")
fig.show()
```

However, a simple `scatter_matrix` or `parallel_coordinates` shows no output. For example, the following does not work:

```
fig = px.scatter_matrix(df, color="species")
fig.show()
```

No errors appear on the console or in the output cell. The cell executes, and that's it. It doesn't show any result.

I did the following:

- Updating conda: `conda update --all -c plotly -c conda-forge`
- Cleaning and rebuilding jupyter lab extensions: `jupyter lab clean` and `jupyter lab build`.
- I also tried the relevant troubleshooting options according to: https://plot.ly/python/troubleshooting/.
- I tried running the notebook in regular Jupyter, and it doesn't work there either, though the start of a plot does appear, with a sad face on the plot, indicating that something is not happy, but I'm not sure what.
- I tried recoding the above using the `plotly.graph_objects` API instead of `plotly.express`. Same outcome.

I still have the same problems.

It's worth noting that I CAN do the following:

```
fig = px.scatter_matrix(df, color="species")
fig.show(renderer='browser')
```

And that automatically opens the browser window and works just fine. So, it seems that the plotly engine itself is fine, there is just something up with the jupyter connection for *some* types of plots.

Any suggestions on where to look, or what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, which version of plotly are you using?  I don't have any problems with `fig = px.scatter_matrix(df, color="species")`

Comment: Good question - I'm using plotly = 4.5, jupyter_core = 4.6.1, jupyter = 1.0.0, jupyterlab = 1.2.6, on Python = 3.7.

Comment: Are you on Linux?

Comment: I am on MacOS 10.15 (Catalina) with plenty of disk space and memory. I did wonder if it was an issue with Jupyter not being allotted enough memory to render the plot.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after trying out a lot of different things to get this working, I finally went back and decided to just clean everything up. I did the following:

- `conda clean --all`
- `conda update --all -c plotly -c defaults -c conda-forge` (The order of the channel specifiers is important!)
- `jupyter labextension update --all`
- `jupyter lab clean`
- `jupyter lab build`

And, I also noticed that my notebook was not trusted. So, I made the notebook trusted. And, now everything is working! There were MANY updates when I did `conda update --all` above because of the order that I used with the channels. I definitely put the `defaults` channel as higher priority, with left far fewer packages installed from `conda-forge`. This changed the version of a lot of packages, but I'm not certain which ones. I could look through the revisions in conda and get that list later, though packages are always being updated, so it might not be relevant.

I wondered if it was possible that setting the notebook to *trusted* was really the only problem? Well, I tried to clear the trust setting:

- `jupyter trust --reset`

And, it still worked. So, I'm inclined to believe that it was not a trust issue with the notebook, but some version conflict with the numerous packages that I updated from the main conda channel `defaults` instead of `conda-forge`.

For the moment, all is well. Thanks, rpanai for chiming in.